# Sane on Raspberry Pi 3 doesn't find ScanSnap iX500

Tags: pi-3, raspberry-pi-os

I would like to install a scanserver on my Raspberry Pi 3 following these [instructions](https://chrisschuld.com/2020/01/network-scanner-with-scansnap-and-raspberry-pi/).
The operating system is the current Raspberry OS: "2021-10-30-raspios-bullseye-armhf-lite".

The step `sudo scanimage >/tmp/out.pnm` give the following result:

```
Output format is not set, using pnm as a default.
scanimage: no SANE devices found
```

When trying the step `sudo scanimage -L` I get the following result:

```
No scanners were identified. If you were expecting something different,
check that the scanner is plugged in, turned on and detected by the
sane-find-scanner tool (if appropriate). Please read the documentation
which came with this software (README, FAQ, manpages).
```

The result from `sudo sane-find-scanner` is the following (skipping the comments):

```
found USB scanner (vendor=0x04c5 [Fujitsu], product=0x132b [ScanSnap iX500]) at libusb:001:005
found USB scanner (vendor=0x0424, product=0xec00) at libusb:001:003
```

An internet search gave me some advice to add the scanner in `/etc/udev/rules.d` which unfortunately does not solve the problem at all. Here are two links:

- https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/184367/scanimage-does-not-find-scanner-unless-sudoed-but-shows-up-with-sane-find-scan
- https://askubuntu.com/questions/178833/scanner-detected-with-sane-find-scanner-but-not-with-scanimage-l-or-sudo-scani

The scanner itself is up to date and scans nicely when connected to a windows machine.

Do you have any hints?

Thanks you very much!

Additional information

```
$ scanimage --version
scanimage (sane-backends) 1.0.31-debian; backend version 1.0.31
```

and

```
$ SANE_DEBUG_DLL=128  scanimage -L 2>&1 | grep -i fuj
[11:36:59.869511] [dll] add_backend: adding backend `fujitsu'
[11:37:04.079736] [dll] load: searching backend `fujitsu' in `/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/sane:/usr/lib/sane:/usr/lib64/sane'
[11:37:04.079790] [dll] load: trying to load `/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/sane/libsane-fujitsu.so.1'
[11:37:04.079862] [dll] load: dlopen()ing `/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/sane/libsane-fujitsu.so.1'
[11:37:04.081730] [dll] init: initializing backend `fujitsu'
[11:37:04.081885] [dll] init: backend `fujitsu' is version 1.0.136
[11:37:06.613099] [dll] sane_exit: calling backend `fujitsu's exit function
```

Next step:

```
$ SANE_DEBUG_FUJITSU=15 scanimage -L
[13:49:54.374247] [fujitsu] sane_get_devices: looking for 'usb 0x04c5 0x132b'
[13:49:54.374332] [fujitsu] attach_one: start
[13:49:54.374408] [fujitsu] attach_one: looking for 'libusb:001:005'
[13:49:54.374498] [fujitsu] connect_fd: start
[13:49:54.374576] [fujitsu] connect_fd: opening USB device
[13:49:54.374921] [fujitsu] connect_fd: could not open device: 3
[13:49:54.375006] [fujitsu] connect_fd: finish
[13:49:54.375093] [fujitsu] sane_get_devices: looking for 'usb 0x04c5 0x132c'
... many 'usb 0x04c5 0x1***'
[13:49:54.378605] [fujitsu] sane_get_devices: looking for 'usb 0x04c5 0x160b'
[13:49:54.378724] [fujitsu] sane_get_devices: found 0 scanner(s)
[13:49:54.378809] [fujitsu] sane_get_devices: finish

No scanners were identified. If you were expecting something different,
check that the scanner is plugged in, turned on and detected by the
sane-find-scanner tool (if appropriate). Please read the documentation
which came with this software (README, FAQ, manpages).
[13:49:56.842368] [fujitsu] sane_exit: start
[13:49:56.842498] [fujitsu] sane_exit: finish
```

```
$ SANE_USB_WORKAROUND=1 scanimage -L

No scanners were identified. If you were expecting something different,
check that the scanner is plugged in, turned on and detected by the
sane-find-scanner tool (if appropriate). Please read the documentation
which came with this software (README, FAQ, manpages).
```

Now with `sudo`:

```
$ sudo SANE_DEBUG_FUJITSU=15 scanimage -L
[11:49:00.589654] [sanei_debug] Setting debug level of fujitsu to 15.
[11:49:00.589850] [fujitsu] sane_init: start
[11:49:00.589909] [fujitsu] sane_init: fujitsu backend 1.0.136, from sane-backends 1.0.31-debian
[11:49:00.589969] [fujitsu] sane_init: finish
[11:49:00.590022] [fujitsu] sane_get_devices: start
[11:49:00.590718] [fujitsu] sane_get_devices: reading config file fujitsu.conf
[11:49:00.590815] [fujitsu] sane_get_devices: setting "buffer-size" to 65536
[11:49:00.590878] [fujitsu] sane_get_devices: looking for 'scsi FUJITSU'
[11:49:00.591023] [fujitsu] sane_get_devices: looking for 'usb 0x04c5 0x1041'
... many 'usb 0x04c5 0x1***'
[11:49:00.592099] [fujitsu] sane_get_devices: looking for 'usb 0x04c5 0x114a'
[11:49:00.592161] [fujitsu] sane_get_devices: config option "buffer-size" (262144) is > 65536, warning!
[11:49:00.592215] [fujitsu] sane_get_devices: setting "buffer-size" to 262144
[11:49:00.592271] [fujitsu] sane_get_devices: looking for 'usb 0x04c5 0x114d'
... many 'usb 0x04c5 0x1***'
[11:49:00.593516] [fujitsu] sane_get_devices: looking for 'usb 0x04c5 0x132b'
[11:49:00.593573] [fujitsu] attach_one: start
[11:49:00.593628] [fujitsu] attach_one: looking for 'libusb:001:004'
[11:49:00.593688] [fujitsu] connect_fd: start
[11:49:00.593741] [fujitsu] connect_fd: opening USB device
[11:49:00.593974] [fujitsu] connect_fd: could not open device: 3
[11:49:00.594033] [fujitsu] connect_fd: finish
[11:49:00.594088] [fujitsu] sane_get_devices: looking for 'usb 0x04c5 0x132c'
... many 'usb 0x04c5 0x1***'
[11:49:00.596646] [fujitsu] sane_get_devices: looking for 'usb 0x04c5 0x160b'
[11:49:00.596733] [fujitsu] sane_get_devices: found 0 scanner(s)
[11:49:00.596791] [fujitsu] sane_get_devices: finish

No scanners were identified. If you were expecting something different,
check that the scanner is plugged in, turned on and detected by the
sane-find-scanner tool (if appropriate). Please read the documentation
which came with this software (README, FAQ, manpages).
[11:49:03.108786] [fujitsu] sane_exit: start
[11:49:03.108919] [fujitsu] sane_exit: finish
```

After installing `lsof` via `apt-get` I have these following results. There is no difference with or without `sudo`. The other number (1, 2, 3, 5) give no response.

```
$ sudo lsof /dev/bus/usb/001/004
lsof: status error on /dev/bus/usb/001/004: No such file or directory
lsof 4.93.2
 latest revision: https://github.com/lsof-org/lsof
 latest FAQ: https://github.com/lsof-org/lsof/blob/master/00FAQ
 latest (non-formatted) man page: https://github.com/lsof-org/lsof/blob/master/Lsof.8
 usage: [-?abhKlnNoOPRtUvVX] [+|-c c] [+|-d s] [+D D] [+|-E] [+|-e s] [+|-f[gG]]
 [-F [f]] [-g [s]] [-i [i]] [+|-L [l]] [+m [m]] [+|-M] [-o [o]] [-p s]
 [+|-r [t]] [-s [p:s]] [-S [t]] [-T [t]] [-u s] [+|-w] [-x [fl]] [--] [names]
```

Here is the result of a different USB cable and the old cable at different ports.

```
$ sudo lsof /dev/bus/usb/001/006
COMMAND PID  USER   FD   TYPE DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
scanbd  418 saned    9u   CHR  189,5      0t0  424 /dev/bus/usb/001/006
$ sudo lsof /dev/bus/usb/001/008
COMMAND PID  USER   FD   TYPE DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
scanbd  418 saned    9u   CHR  189,7      0t0  428 /dev/bus/usb/001/008
```

However, the debug print and workaround return the same results.

Comment: Are the `sane-backends` installed? Does `/etc/sane.d/fujitsu.conf` contain the line `usb 0x04c5 0x132b` (should be in a normal distribution)? What happens if you add `usb 0x0424 0xec00` to that file?

Comment: Yes, the file contains this line. When I add the second line, nothing changes. The second line (`0x0424`) is only shown with root privileges.

Comment: What does `scanimage --version` say?

Comment: and  also `SANE_DEBUG_DLL=128  scanimage -L 2>&1 | grep -i fuj`? (add the answer to your question)

Comment: Hallo @LjmDullaart! I add the two results.

Comment: That means that the fujitsu-backend (needed for this scanner) works, but it cannot recognize the scanner. Next step would be to see what the Fujitsu-backend sees at the problem. Try `SANE_DEBUG_FUJITSU=15 scanimage -L`.  This will produce a lot of output. We're interested in the part that follows `[fujitsu] sane_get_devices: looking for 'usb 0x04c5 0x132b'`; you can drop anything before that.

Comment: If it is an USB problem, you may also try `SANE_USB_WORKAROUND=1 scanimage -L`.

Comment: @LjmDullaart Thanks! I added the results to my question.

Comment: The ` connect_fd: could not open device: 3` suggests that there is a permission problem. Can you try it as root to see if it produces differnt errors?

Comment: @LjmDullaart I add the call with root rights.

Comment: The backend is apparently unable to open your scanner, for some reason. It is a `libusb` problem, somehow. Could there be another process holding this device (`lsof /dev/bus/usb/001/004`)?

Comment: @LjmDullaart I added the result from lsof. Is the lite version of Raspberry OS a possible root cause?

Comment: You'll need to re-check the scanner-ID if `lsof` cannot find it. The `001/004` came from the  `'libusb:001:004'` in the `scanimage -L` output.  Been searching a bit, but it looks more and more like an USB issue. Try different cables, without, or with hub, other USB ports.

Comment: @LjmDullaart I tried different ports and a different cable. Before I posted my question I tried my old Pi1 and bought a new Pi3 because I thought this could be the issue.

Comment: Any further ideas? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Been away a bit, sorry. Your usb-device is locked by `scanbd`, and that seems the reason that `scanimage` cannot open it. Try `sudo systemctl stop scanbd` before scanning with `scanimage`.

Comment: @LjmDullaart Wonderful! Now `-L` returns the scanner and it produce `pnm` files. However, I need `scanbd` to get a trigger from the scanner button. Is it possible to unlock the usb device without missing the button events?

Comment: No. However, you should be able to access the scanner via `scanbd` (haven't tried it myself) See https://sodocumentation.net/raspberry-pi/topic/6701/create-a-scan-station-with-scanbd--raspbian-

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We used the following method to search for the problem.

Step 1: verify, that the back-end is installed and enabled. In this case, the scanner was found by `sudo sane-find-scanner`. The venor an product ID were present in `/etc/sane.d/fujitsu.conf`, which is the config file for the applicable backend.

Step 2: The correct backend is tested during start-up. We verified this with `SANE_DEBUG_DLL=128  scanimage -L 2>&1 | grep -i fuj`

Step 3: Check why the Fujitsu backend failed to recognize the scanner with `SANE_DEBUG_FUJITSU=15 scanimage -L`. This produced a lot of output, but the most important part was:

```
[11:49:00.593516] [fujitsu] sane_get_devices: looking for 'usb 0x04c5 0x132b'
[11:49:00.593573] [fujitsu] attach_one: start
[11:49:00.593628] [fujitsu] attach_one: looking for 'libusb:001:004'
[11:49:00.593688] [fujitsu] connect_fd: start
[11:49:00.593741] [fujitsu] connect_fd: opening USB device
[11:49:00.593974] [fujitsu] connect_fd: could not open device: 3
[11:49:00.594033] [fujitsu] connect_fd: finish
```

The backend could not open the device for some reason. Most of the times, this is a permission problem, but here, the problem also manifested when scanning as `root`. It might be, that a different process is holding the device.

Step 4: Is there some process that is holding the device? With `sudo lsof /dev/bus/usb/001/006` (the scanner was device 6 on bus 1. which can be found with `lsusb`). The output revealed that

```
COMMAND PID  USER   FD   TYPE DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
scanbd  418 saned    9u   CHR  189,5      0t0  424 /dev/bus/usb/001/006
```

the process `scanbd` is holding the device. Killing `scanbd` freed the scanner and `scanimage` was able to provide a scan.

On a system with a properly configured `scanbd`, it should be possible to scan with `scanimage` using the net-backend. I have never tried this though.